# How can I make a function call with filepath?

Tags: c++, linux, file, function, filepath

I just want to call a function with filepath which is "/home/merve/merve.txt":

```
void GenerateUnecryptedData(const char* pathToUnencryptedFile)
{
      // File structure:
      int offset=0;
      ofstream myfile;
      myfile.open ("pathToUnencryptedFile", ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary);

      // + 20 bytes of arbitrarily chosen data (offset: 0)
      myfile.seekp(offset) << CD ;
      // + IV (Initialization Vector) 16 bytes (offset: 20)
      offset=20;
      myfile.seekp(offset) << IV;
      offset=36;
      // + 48 bytes of Plain Text(offset: 36)
      //- PLAINTEXT = ENCRYPTEDBurada herhangi birsey yaziyor olabilir
      myfile.seekp(offset) << PLAINTEXT ;

}
```

So how can I call my function?

By the way, I'm not so sure my code will work? I'm going to try after my function call.

I'm just a beginner so please make it simpler for me!

Comment: `myfile.open ("pathToUnencryptedFile"`... You probably meant to pass the argument variable to `open` instead of a string literal which contains the name of the variable. Lose the quotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass it in as a variable. If you put quotes around it, it is interpreted as a `string` literal. Also I'd recommend using `std::string` instead of `char*`

```
void GenerateUnecryptedData(std::string const pathToUnencryptedFile)
{
    ofstream myFile{pathToUnencryptedFile, ios::out | ios::app | ios::binary};
}
```

Then you'd call it as

```
GenerateUnecryptedData("/home/merve/merve.txt");
```